# Go: relative http.Redirect behind Apache mod_proxy

Tags: apache, go, mod-proxy

I have a simple go server listening on `:8888`.

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "net/http"
)

func main() {

  http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("redirecting to foo")
    http.Redirect(w, r, "foo", http.StatusFound)
  })

  http.HandleFunc("/foo", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("fooooo"))
  })

  if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8888", nil); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}
```

I have this sitting behind apache which proxies all requests to `/bar/*` to the go server.
I'm using `ProxyPassMatch` to do this.

```
 ProxyPassMatch ^/bar/?(:?(.*))?$ http://localhost:8888/$2
```

Problem is that is what when I go to `/bar/` I get redirected to `/foo` instead of `/bar/foo`

Is there a way to get this working or do I need to prefix all my redirects with `/bar`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want Apache to rewrite locations in redirect responses, you'll need to also include the [ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) directive in your configuration.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
ProxyPassReverse /bar/ http://localhost:8888/
```

Comment: I added the `ProxyPassReverse` directive after `ProxyPassMatch` and it did not make a difference. I checked the logs but couldn't find anything useful. Suggestions?